# UIRefreshControl adds strange inset by default

Tags: ios, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm adding a UIRefreshControl to a pretty default UITableView by doing...

iOS SDK 8.1
self being an instance of UITableViewController

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refreshControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor flatPeterRiverColor];
refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[refreshControl addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(triggerSync)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self setRefreshControl:refreshControl];
```

What happens is the following:

[image: Example of whats happening]

There is a strange top inset which I've never set up and which only appears when the UIRefreshControl has been set. Has anyone experienced this before? I'm pretty sure it worked well that way in with iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, I don't know if you're still experiencing it but for those who wonder how to fix it I found out a quick solution.

You just have to set height for header in section.
I tried first with 0 but it gave no result.

So I set it to 1.0 for all section and it worked.

Hope this help

Comment: Actually, this looks like it's due to the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property.